# How to load data with ajax and jquery from external db with no page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have got a problem with this small script. I would like to query db Content on a simple html page with no page refresh.

```
    <form method="get" name="formrrv" id="formrrv">
          <input type="hidden" name="calculate" value="1">
          <input type="hidden" name="func" value="rrvform">      
          <div class="searchbox">              
            <input type="checkbox" value="0" name="sb"> no<br>
            <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="sb"> yes<br> 
            <script>
              $('input[type="checkbox"][name="sb"]').on('change', function() {
                $('input[type="checkbox"][name="sb"]').not(this).prop('checked', ! this.checked);
              });
            </script>

            <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="status"> Single<br>
            <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="status"> family<br>
            <script>
              $('input[type="checkbox"][name="status"]').on('change', function() {
                $('input[type="checkbox"][name="status"]').not(this).prop('checked', ! this.checked);
              });
            </script>  
<input  id="maxage" name="maxage" value="">                     
            <input name="price" id="price" name="price" value=""> EUR
            <br>
            <button class="submit" name="submit" onclick="getPage();">search</button>        
            <br>
          </div>
        </form>
        <div id="output">werwerwerwewerwer</div>         
        <script>        
          function getPage() {
            $('#output').html('Hole Daten');
            jQuery.ajax({                               
                url: "rrv2.php",                    
                data: {
                calculate:'1', 
                func:'rrvform', 
                sb:sb, 
                status:status, 
                maxage:maxage, 
                price:price
              }, 
                type: "get",
                success:function(data){$('#output').html(data);}
            });   
          }
        </script>
```

So rrv2.php is defintely working if vars are transfered per get. Can someone please help?

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console?

Comment: I wonder if you need to prevent the default behavior of the submit button or not .

Comment: `onclick="getPage(); return false;"`  Your button is still submitting the form.  You need to stop it from doing that.

Comment: ok, i uncommented the <form> but still no result...

Comment: oh... "ReferenceError: sb is not defined" i forgot to define before.

Comment: so e.g.var status = $(this).data('status')?

Comment: @SpencerDoak `submit: The button submits the form data to the server. This is the default if the attribute is not specified, or if the attribute is dynamically changed to an empty or invalid value.`  From [the Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)

Comment: can PLEASE someone help?

Comment: @franknotechnico As you pointed out, you have undefined variables. Start by fixing that.

Comment: ok i changed submit button to a simple input submit button (as before)

Comment: Patrick Q > yes i did "var sb = document.getElementById('sb').value;"

Comment: YES, it works, GREAT... thank you all so much...

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work fine:

```
<form method="get" name="formrrv" id="formrrv">
  <input type="hidden" name="calculate" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="func" value="rrvform">      
  <div class="searchbox">              
    <input type="checkbox" value="0" name="sb"> no<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="sb"> yes<br> 
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="status"> Single<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="status"> family<br>
    <input  id="maxage" name="maxage" value="">                     
    <input name="price" id="price" name="price" value=""> EUR
    <br>
    <button class="submit" name="submit" id="submit-button">search</button>        
    <br>
  </div>
</form>
<div id="output">werwerwerwewerwer</div>         
<script>
$(document).on('click', '#submit-button', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "rrv2.php",
    data: $('#formrrv').serialize(),
    type: 'GET', // I think GET is default, if so this can be removed
    beforeSend: function() {
      $('#output').html('Hole Daten');
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('#output').html(data);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

I would suggest adding some validation to make sure at least one of your checkboxes is checked or better still, change them to radio buttons with your default pre-selected.